# Произношение слова «декабрь»

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Правильно ли произносить букву ы в этом слове, после б? Если да, все ли произносят эту букву, или произношение отличается в разных регионах?

Какие ещё есть такие слова, чтобы в общем случае сформулировать правило? Мне кажется, нужно, чтобы последняя буква была л или р, а предпоследняя — глухая или парная звонкая.

Не смог найти источники в интернете по этой теме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Произносить звук Ы - акцентировано, именно как отдельный звук - неправильно.**
Но так никто и не произносит.
А вот что касается того, что там на самом деле произносится...
Это вопрос непростой. Если вкратце, то перед звучными (сонорными) звуками Р и Л (реже - Н и М) в некоторых сочетаниях возникает призвук сверхраткого звука, среднего межде Э и Ы. С некоторым допущением его можно назвать звуком "шва", позаимствовав такое название из иврита.

Диалекты тут ни при чем. Вопрос, скорее, в том, кто как эту "шва" слышит.
Поэты часто слышат. Классический пример (я его тут несколько раз приводил в ответах на подобные вопросы) - у Саши Черного.

*Ревет сынок. Побит за двойку с плюсом,

Жена на локоны взяла последний рубль,

Супруг, убитый лавочкой и флюсом,

Подсчитывает месячную убыль.*
("Обстановочка")

"Рубль" прекрасно рифмуется с "убыль", причем никому слух не режет. Это доказывает, что "шва" перед Л действительно вклинивается. Но вряд ли кому-то придет в голову на этом основании считать изредко встречающееся произношение "рубЫль" нормативным.

> Мне кажется, нужно, чтобы последняя буква была л или р, а
> предпоследняя — глухая или парная звонкая.

Не совсем. Доля истины у вас есть, но там немножко по-другому. Этот звук в разной степени возникает на скоплении согласных при любом повышении звучности, в первую очередь - перед сонорными, если им предшествует любой несонорный звук. Но не только.

Произнесите-ка по русски армянское имя "Мкрт(ы)ч" - так там в трех местах шва возникнет (Мэкэртэч). Самое интересное, что это близко к армянской фонетике (кроме последнего слога, в армянском там именно ы/и, не шва).

Comment: Как понять «в разной степени»? Можете тоже привести примеры? И если «шва» возникает не перед сонорными, но в «более русских» словах. Ещё по вашему, выходит, что в слове «жизнь», например, тоже есть этот звук, ведь «з» не сонорный. Или нет?

Comment: @Семен *в слове «жизнь», например, тоже есть этот звук* - есть. А что? *«более русских» словах* - не понял. При чем тут русскость слова? *Как понять «в разной степени»?* - где-то он лучше слышен, где-то хуже. Я затрудняюсь объяснить по-иному. )))

Comment: Спасибо, поискал, что вопрос задавали уже не раз здесь, просто если неизвестно, что так называется, сложно найти